# How to convert tflite_graph.pb to detect.tflite properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api, tensorflow-lite

I am using tensorflow object-detection api for training a custom model using ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_05_09 from tensorflow [model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md).

I successfully trained the model and test it out using a script provided in [this tutorial](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10#5-create-label-map-and-configure-training).

Here is the problem, I need a **detect.tflite** to use it in my target machine (an embedded system). But when I actually make a tflite out of my model, it **outputs almost nothing** and when it does, its a **wrong detection**. To make the .tflite file, I first used `export_tflite_ssd_graph.py` and then `toco` on the output with this command by following [the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_examples) and some google searches:

> `toco --graph_def_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/tflite_graph.pb --output_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/detect.tflite --input_shapes=1,300,300,3 --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor --output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3'  --allow_custom_ops`

Also, the code I'm using for detection task from .tflite is working properly, as I tested it with ssd_mobilenet_v3_small_coco detect.tflite file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with the `toco` command. Some documents that I used were outdated and misled me. `toco` is deprecated and I should have used `tflite_convert` tool instead.

Here is the full command I used (run from your training directory):

> tflite_convert --graph_def_file tflite_inference_graph/tflite_graph.pb
> --output_file=./detect.tflite --output_format=TFLITE --input_shapes=1,300,300,3 --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor --output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3'
> --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 --mean_values=128 --std_dev_values=127 --change_concat_input_ranges=false --allow_custom_ops

I did the training on ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_05_09 model and added this at the end of my .config file.

```
 graph_rewriter {
  quantization {
    delay: 400
    weight_bits: 8
    activation_bits: 8
  }
}
```

Also I used this command to generate tflite_graph.pb in tflite_inference_graph directory:

> `python export_tflite_ssd_graph.py  --pipeline_config_path 2020-05-17_train_ssdlite_v2/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix 2020-05-17_train_ssdlite_v2/train/model.ckpt-1146 --output_directory 2020-05-17_train_ssdlite_v2/tflite_inference_graph --add_postprocessing_op=true`

Note: I wanted to use a quantized model on my embedded system. That is the reason I added graph_rewriter in the config file and  --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 in my tflite_convert command.

Comment: it would be of great value if you could add some references that you used to come to the presented solution to your problem